# How to drop and create new repositories with a subversion server?

Tags: svn, administration

Ok so I just did something boneheaded.

I'm setting up a subversion server for the first time ever that will be used by contractors.  I did the 1 click setup, created my project and did my first check in of our application thinking that I'll go through later and remove the password information in the connection string in the configuration file.

Duh...

So now I need to delete that project within the repository and create it again so I can do the checkin this time without the password.  Looking through the options for svnadmin help I don't see any options for deleting a repository.

How do I do this?  Easy points here!

Comment: The title asks how to recreate a repository, but you actually want to purge a file from an existing repository. Consider changing the title, or splitting it out into a separate question.

Comment: Well, no I imagine I will never want to purge a file from the repository after this one time since whats the point then.  I'd rather have this more important information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To delete the project repository, just delete the folder from the server, then do svnadmin create again.

Will is right, I didn't read the password sentence correctly. Checking out and deleting won't help with the security concerns. When in doubt, [follow the book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/) or check CMS's link.

Answer (score 6):

You can remove the file and purge all its history, and then re-import it clean.

Check this from the SVN FAQ:

[How do I completely remove a file from the repository's history?](http://subversion.tigris.org/faq.html#removal)

Answer (score -1):

Just deleting the files from the current revision and doing a commit won't help  with security concerns.  The password will still exist in an old revision of the repository for the now-deleted file.  CMS's FAQ link should help as well.