# Subversion: Expected format '3' of repository; found format '5'

Tags: svn, administration

Well I've gotten myself in a pickle

I did the [subversion 1 click setup](http://svn1clicksetup.tigris.org/) and it worked great.  However, in setting up my repository I accidentally committed a file that I shouldn't have.  Rather than jumping through the hoops of purging a file I deleted the repository and recreated it using "svnadmin create" [as recommended to me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/344406/how-to-drop-and-create-new-repositories-with-a-subversion-server).

Now however I am recieving the notorious Expected format '3' of repository; found format '5' error when I try to either import to the repository, or just even browse to it.

When I tried to uninstall subversion so that I could re-run the 1 click setup the uninstall failed and the 1 click setup won't overwrite whats already there.

From googling, this seems to be like some sort of versioning error but I don't see how that can be the case since I only ever installed the one version.

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would appear that the 'one click setup' is based on an ancient version of SVN, but somehow you've also got a more up-to-date version of svnadmin which has created a newer repository.

I can't help you with your failed install/uninstall, but when you finally get rid of all the detritus of the 1-click install, then I'd try again, using something more up-to-date.

Here is a more up-to-date version in a nice package:

http://www.collab.net/downloads/subversion/

And here is the same stuff in just a .ZIP file which contains all the bits you need:

http://subversion.tigris.org/servlets/ProjectDocumentList?folderID=91

Comment: Will, I don't want anything to do with python or ruby or anything would I download wvn-win32-1.5.4.zip?

Comment: Yup, this took forever to get working.  What a pain...

PS. The collabnet stuff didn't work for me at all.  It didn't even add the SVN_ADMIN environmental variable.  Probably I was just confused but I found it to be easeir just to do the install manually