# svnadmin not creating correct repository version

Tags: svn, repository, version, svnadmin, fsfs

I created an SVN repository with svnadmin 1.7.7, but the repository format is wrong. I end up getting

```
svnadmin: E165005: Expected repository format '3' or '5'; found format '12'
```

when I try to load the repository.

```
$ /svr/svn/repositories> ls -l SvnCreateTest
SvnCreateTest: No such file or directory
$ /svr/svn/repositories> mkdir SvnCreateTest
$ /svr/svn/repositories> ../csvn/bin/svnadmin create SvnCreateTest
$ /svr/svn/repositories> cat SvnCreateTest/format
5
$ /svr/svn/repositories> cat SvnCreateTest/db/format
4
layout sharded 1000
$ /svr/svn/repositories> ../csvn/bin/svnadmin --version
svnadmin, version 1.7.7 (r1393599)
   compiled Oct 16 2012, 19:23:32

Copyright (C) 2012 The Apache Software Foundation.
This software consists of contributions made by many people; see the NOTICE
file for more information.
Subversion is open source software, see http://subversion.apache.org/

The following repository back-end (FS) modules are available:

* fs_fs : Module for working with a plain file (FSFS) repository.

$ /svr/svn/repositories>
```

From what I've read, version 1.7.7 should create a format 12 repository. What am I missing?

Comment: Can you share the command you used to load the repository?

Comment: C:/cygwin/bin/svnadmin.exe load --parent-dir . C:/cygwin/home/clark_andrew/GIT_TO_SVN/cps-commons/.svn

Comment: I should mention that I'm using Subclipse 1.8.3 on my PC. I was under the impression it is compatible with server version 1.7.7.

Comment: Are you sure this is the right command? I cannot see a redirection of a dump file from *stdin* anywhere.

Comment: it turns out I was using the import tool (svnimporter by Polarion) incorrectly. Man, I hate user error, especially when the user is me :-/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Weird Apache2.2 SVN error, "Expected repository format '3' or '5'; found format '9'"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/557701/weird-apache2-2-svn-error-expected-repository-format-3-or-5-found-format)