# Possible to migrate an SVN repo to git that is a local copy only?

Tags: git, svn, github, git-svn

I have a clone of an SVN repo on my machine for which the SVN server is unreachable. The program used for cloning is Tortoise SVN for Windows.

Is there any way to import the commit history of the repo into a git repository on github?

I tried

```
svnadmin dump repo/.svn > svn.dump
```

Resulting in

```
svnadmin: E165005: Expected repository format '3' or '5'; found format '12'
```

Which seems to be misleading, meaning I cannot dump that copy. But are there options other than dumping?

Comment: maybe see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/557701/weird-apache2-2-svn-error-expected-repository-format-3-or-5-found-format

Answer (score 2):

I suspect now this is impossible. Local SVN checkout doesn't contain enough information to serve as a repository. There is no history information — it's all on the server.

Your only way is to simply remove .svn subdirectories and run `git init && git add .` to create a repository with your files. No history.

Comment: Even with Tortoise? I thought maybe there is some extra information stored by it..

Comment: How much extra info can you see with T…SVN now when you're disconnected? Can you see `svn log`?