# Rebol Call Command doesn't behave exactly like Dos command (ex with Subversion command line)

Tags: rebol

This Subversion import command works on dos command line:

```
"C:\Program Files\Subversion\bin\svn.exe" import c:\myproj file:///c:/svnrepo/myproj -m "test"
```

If I try to send the same command with Rebol Call Command with this script:

```
Print "This command will and your files to the repository without requiring a working copy"    
repo-directory: to-local-file ask "repo: "
project-subdirectory: to-local-file ask "project: "
source-directory: to-local-file ask "source directory: "
comment: ask "comment: "
command: rejoin [{"} Subversion.Directory "bin\svn.exe" {"} " import " source-directory " file:///" (replace/all (to-local-file repo-directory) "\" "/") "/" project-subdirectory " -m " {"} comment {"}]
call/wait/console command
```

I will get this

```
repo: c:\svnrepo
project: myproj
source directory: c:\myproj
comment: test
svn: The given propagation message is a path (-F was this intended ?) ; force with 
 '--force-log'
== 1
```

The value of command is the same as the Dos command:

```
>> command
== {"C:\Program Files\Subversion\bin\svn.exe" import c:\myproj file:///c:/svnrepo/m
yproj -m "test"}
>>
```

So I appended --force-log and it did then work but I still would like to know the reason Rebol doesn't behave like Dos Command if there is one that I ignore.

Comment: What does [print command] look like? Any variations from the expected formatted string that you want to use in CALL ?

Comment: I don't understand what you means by print command as I just put above the output of command in console: isn't this the same output as print ?

Comment: Good idea, can't test it yet as I have messed something with subversion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/344691/subversion-expected-format-3-of-repository-found-format-5

Answer (score 1):

And if you write the command to say %script.cmd and call that from Rebol, do you get the desired effect?