# subversion and tortoise repositroies problem

Tags: tortoisesvn

I installed the subversion svn 1.2.3 and tortoise svn 1.6.14 on the server with svnservice according to following link 
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/architecture/Subversion_on_Windows.aspx

and after this I installed these on client m/c as same .

now when I click on tsvn checkout on client m/c then it gives an error like:

> Error: Expected format '3' of repository; found format '5'

Comment: The svn 1.2.3 is really old...current SVN version is 1.6.15 ! Update as fast as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Quick search returned this: [Subversion: Expected format '3' of repository; found format '5'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/344691/subversion-expected-format-3-of-repository-found-format-5)  at a guess you have also used this 1click setup?

Edit: I'd also recommend getting the CollabNet command-line client :)

Answer (score 0):

I have had this problem when the client and server are of different major version numbers as you indicate in your question.  Have a look at the help provided by the tortoise client.  It provides an excellent description of how to setup a server on windows.  It is accessed by right-clicking in windows explorer, then select TortoiseSVN->Help.  This opens a CHM file that has alot of good information here.